# Is it possible to redirect output of a Win32 application to a Picture Box?

Tags: c#, winapi, user32

I've previously seen code samples that redirect Windows Media Player's output to a Picturebox in C#. I am interested in doing this for other Win32 applications. Considering the fact that I can get hWnd handle of the process that I want to redirect its output, how can I accomplish my goal?

I can minimize/maximize the process' window using user32.dll's ShowWindow method, so I am guessing there should be a solution for my problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest reading about Desktop Windows Manager (feature introduced in Windows Vista):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969540(v=VS.85).aspx

I believe it has the capabilities you seek.

I would start by reading about the [`DwmRegisterThumbnail`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969521.aspx) function, which attaches two `HWND`s so that one window is also painted on the second one. Using this method you may be able to cause Windows Media Player to be drawn on the `HWND` obtained from your `PictureBox.Handle` property.

There are also a lot of questions and answers about this topic here in StackOverflow. Using the search word "dwm" yields quite a few results: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=dwm

Comment: Unfortunately, I need this for a Windows XP application. Is it possible for me to create HWND of a process beforehand or is this assigned by Windows?